# symfony: trying to use my own method to show a list in the backend. Undefined offset notice

Tags: symfony1, backend

i'm trying to use my own method to show a list in the backend:

class ShopOrderPeer extends BaseShopOrderPeer {

```
public static function getOrdini()
{
    $con = Propel::getConnection();
    $sql = "select customers_name, value, date_purchased, orders_status from shop_orders LEFT JOIN shop_orders_total  ON shop_orders.orders_id = shop_orders_total.orders_id";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $ordini = self::populateObjects($stmt);


    return $ordini;

}
```

}

And this is my generator.yml

```
generator:
  class: sfPropelGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           ShopOrder
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ShopOrder
    plural:                ShopOrders
    route_prefix:          shop_order
    with_propel_route:     1
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      actions: ~
      fields:  ~
      list:
        display: [customers_name, date_purchased, orders_status ]
        peer_method:  getOrdini
      filter:  ~
      form:    ~
      edit:    ~
      new:     ~
```

When i load the page of the list, the list is showed but I get this erro messages

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /home/javier/Aptana_Studio_Workspace/dev_repo/lib/model/om/BaseShopOrder.php on line 1864
Call Stack
#  Time  Memory  Function  Location
1  0.0017  324556  {main}( )  ../backend_dev.php:0
2  0.0891  4457868  sfContext->dispatch( )  ../backend_dev.php:13
3  0.0891  4457912  sfFrontWebController->dispatch( )  ../sfContext.class.php:170
4  0.0892  4464168  sfController->forward( )  ../sfFrontWebController.class.php:48
5  0.1181  5054656  sfFilterChain->execute( )  ../sfController.class.php:229
6  0.1188  5061248  sfRenderingFilter->execute( )  ../sfFilterChain.class.php:53
7  0.1188  5061248  sfFilterChain->execute( )  ../sfRenderingFilter.class.php:33
8  0.1191  5070452  sfBasicSecurityFilter->execute( )  ../sfFilterChain.class.php:53
9  0.1192  5070496  sfFilterChain->execute( )  ../sfBasicSecurityFilter.class.php:72
10  0.1196  5082256  sfExecutionFilter->execute( )  ../sfFilterChain.class.php:53
11  0.2778  11817440  sfExecutionFilter->handleView( )  ../sfExecutionFilter.class.php:47
12  0.2778  11817440  sfExecutionFilter->executeView( )  ../sfExecutionFilter.class.php:116
13  0.2815  11859256  sfPHPView->render( )  ../sfExecutionFilter.class.php:155
14  0.2815  11859632  sfPHPView->renderFile( )  ../sfPHPView.class.php:179
15  0.2855  11973804  require('/home/javier/Aptana_Studio_Workspace/dev_repo/cache/backend/dev/modules/autoOrdini/templates/indexSuccess.php')  ../sfPHPView.class.php:75
16  3.0826  115065148  include_partial( )  ../indexSuccess.php:19
17  3.0826  115065148  get_partial( )  ../PartialHelper.php:180
18  3.0831  115068964  sfPartialView->render( )  ../PartialHelper.php:218
19  3.0832  115070248  sfPHPView->renderFile( )  ../sfPartialView.class.php:110
20  3.0866  115161828  require( '/home/javier/Aptana_Studio_Workspace/dev_repo_cashgold/cache/backend/dev/modules/autoOrdini/templates/_list.php' )  ../sfPHPView.class.php:75
21  3.6215  115636256  sfPropelPager->getResults( )  ../_list.php:28
22  3.6215  115636668  call_user_func ( )  ../sfPropelPager.class.php:117
23  3.6216  115636696  ShopOrderPeer::getOrdini( )  ../sfPropelPager.class.php:0
24  3.6227  115676928  BaseShopOrderPeer::populateObjects( )  ../ShopOrderPeer.php:31
25  3.6229  115684084  BaseShopOrder->hydrate( )
```

And then:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 Notice:
>   Undefined offset: 6 ....

This is the file BaseShopOrder.php

```
try {

            $this->orders_id = ($row[$startcol + 0] !== null) ? (int) $row[$startcol + 0] : null;
            $this->sfgu_id = ($row[$startcol + 1] !== null) ? (int) $row[$startcol + 1] : null;
            $this->utenti_email = ($row[$startcol + 2] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 2] : null;
            $this->utenti_telefono = ($row[$startcol + 3] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 3] : null;
            $this->customers_name = ($row[$startcol + 4] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 4] : null;            // line 1864
            $this->customers_company = ($row[$startcol + 5] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 5] : null;
            $this->customers_street_address = ($row[$startcol + 6] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 6] : null;
            $this->customers_suburb = ($row[$startcol + 7] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 7] : null;
            $this->customers_city = ($row[$startcol + 8] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 8] : null;
            $this->customers_postcode = ($row[$startcol + 9] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 9] : null;
            $this->customers_state = ($row[$startcol + 10] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 10] : null;
            $this->customers_country = ($row[$startcol + 11] !== null) ? (string) $row[$startcol + 11] : null;
```

Any idea?

Javi

Comment: Workaround: instead of select customers_name, value, date_purchased, orders_status from shop_orders LEFT JOIN ...,  select * LEFT JOIN ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SomePeer::populateObjects() is designed to be used with SomePeer::doSelect().

populateObjects() expects the query to contain ALL off the columns that exist in the table you are querying.  This is why doing SELECT * FROM ... has worked for you.

However, your workaround is not advised because if for some reason the order of the columns in your database changes your database will return the columns in a different order to what your populateObjects() is expecting.

It's much safer to write a Criteria object.  Then you can use the peer method addSelectColumns if you wish, however this is not necessary if you use doSelect... from your peer class as it is called for you.

The propel website has some good documentation on Criteria, just check which version of Propel you have installed first.

http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation